# Automatically adjusting process priorities under Linux

Tags: linux, process

I'm trying to write a program that automatically sets process priorities based on a configuration file (basically path - priority pairs).

I thought the best solution would be a kernel module that replaces the execve() system call. Too bad, the system call table isn't exported in kernel versions > 2.6.0, so it's not possible to replace system calls without *really* ugly hacks.

I do *not* want to do the following:

-Replace binaries with shell scripts, that start and renice the binaries.
-Patch/recompile my stock Ubuntu kernel
-Do ugly hacks like reading kernel executable memory and guessing the syscall table location
-Polling of running processes

I *really* want to be:

-Able to control the priority of any process based on it's executable path, and a configuration file. Rules apply to any user.

Does anyone of you have any ideas on how to complete this task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've settled for a polling solution, most of the features you want to implement already exist in the [Automatic Nice Daemon](http://manpages.org/and/8). You can configure nice levels for processes based on process name, user and group. It's even possible to adjust process priorities dynamically based on how much CPU time it has used so far.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes polling is a necessity, and even *more* optimal in the end -- believe it or not. It depends on a lot of variables.

If the polling overhead is low-enough, it far exceeds the added complexity, cost, and RISK of developing your own style kernel hooks to get notified of the changes you need. That said, *when* hooks or notification events are available, or can be easily injected, they should certainly be used if the situation calls.

This is classic programmer 'perfection' thinking. As engineers, we strive for perfection. This is the real world though and sometimes compromises must be made. Ironically, the more perfect solution may be the less efficient one in some cases.

I develop a similar 'process and process priority optimization automation' tool for Windows called Process Lasso (not an advertisement, its free). I had a similar choice to make and have a hybrid solution in place. Kernel mode hooks are available for certain process related events in Windows (creation and destruction), but they not only aren't exposed at user mode, but also aren't helpful at monitoring other process metrics. I don't think any OS is going to natively inform you of any change to any process metric. The overhead for that many different hooks might be much greater than simple polling.

Lastly, considering the HIGH frequency of process changes, it may be better to handle all changes at once (polling at interval) vs. notification events/hooks, which may have to be processed many more times per second.

You are RIGHT to stay away from scripts. Why? Because they are slow(er). Of course, the linux scheduler does a fairly good job at handling CPU bound threads by downgrading their priority and rewarding (upgrading) the priority of I/O bound threads -- so even in high loads a script *should* be responsive I guess.

Comment: I admit that polling is _necessary_, _sometimes_. But in my opinion, in this case, it would be slow(er) and very race condition-ish. I have several hundreds or thousands of processes and polling them every second or so is definitely slower than firing a hook at process start.

Comment: Yes, I certainly agree, so long as you are looking only at process creation and destruction. If you were tracking changes to virtual memory usage, for instance, then obviously you'd have to poll because getting a notification for every change would result in a crapload of notifications per second for that single metric. You get my point ;).

Comment: "This is classic programmer 'perfection' thinking. As engineers, we strive for perfection. This is the real world though and sometimes compromises must be made.", :D Yes, you are right. This "real world" stuff involves buggy and incomplete kernel, so I must stay with polling. "Good enaugh".

Comment: @netom: I did not say create crap. I should have left that comment out. I was just saying that sometimes the theoretically best solution isn't the most pragmatic. Obviously a solution that is crap is no good solution for anybody. You can go to either extreme -- as with all things, there is balance involved. At the time I commented I had been in a project where they kept rewriting everything to achieve even better code, but perpetually delaying any release -- so that's one extreme. The other extreme is just throwing some crap out there, something no self-respecting programmer should ever do.

Answer (score 2):

There's another point of attack you might consider: replace the system's [dynamic linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker#GNU.2FLinux) with a modified one which applies your logic.  (See this [paper](http://www3.interscience.wiley.com/cgi-bin/fulltext/123217739/PDFSTART) for some nice examples of what's possible from the largely neglected art of linker hacking).

Where this approach will have problems is with purely statically linked binaries.  I doubt there's much on a modern system which actually doesn't link something dynamically (things like [busybox-static](http://packages.debian.org/stable/busybox-static) being the obvious exceptions, although you might regard the ability to get a minimal shell outside of your controls as a feature when it all goes horribly wrong), so this may not be a big deal.  On the other hand, if the priority policies are intended to bring some order to an overloaded shared multi-user system then you might see smart users preparing static-linked versions of apps to avoid linker-imposed priorities.

Comment: I will definitely check this possibility, thank you. Now I have to figure out how to replace / hack libc somewhere _very_ early in the boot process, without modifying files that come with Ubuntu packages (I still want to upgrade the system when something new comes out).

Comment: Surely you'd just prepare a modified libc, package it as a .deb, and install it (replacing the default libc) on the systems you want be be able to apply these policies on ?  My assumption is virtually everything dynamically links libc these days, so existing binaries should just pick up the new ldd/ld-linux.so quite happily.

Comment: Ok, this is fine, but I don't want to lose the simplicity of automatic updates. Is there any way to "patch" existing binaries? I mean to replace certain functions, with, say, a linker script or such thing? I'm really not an expert in linker specific issues.

Comment: Neither am I.  If a new libc came out with security fixes, your systems would have the choice of installing it and losing your modified linker, or waiting for you to get your own version of the update out.  It'd be nice for you if the linker was more separated from the rest of libc in a separate package as the chances are libc updates (which are fairly rare anyway) might not need to touch the linker... but things aren't actually so.  And overwriting a particular libc's linker with one compiled from a previous version of libc seems like a bad idea (risk of completely broken system?)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just iterate through /proc/*nnn*/exe to get the pathname of the running image. Only use the ones with slashes, the others are kernel procs.

Check to see if you have already processed that one, otherwise look up the new priority in your configuration file and use renice(8) to tweak its priority.

Comment: Doesn't that count as "polling of running processes" (which the questioner wants to avoid) ?

Comment: I suppose but it might still be the best approach.

Comment: Yes timday, this is what I don't want to do. But this solution is not _that_ bad, I could live with it. But I don't like polling, and I don't like algorithms that doesn't run in O(1) ;) . This is polling in O(n), and I don't _like_ it, but it _will_ work I'm sure. If the linker hack won't work, I'm afraid I have to go on with this solution. DigitalRoss, thanks for thinking outside the box ;)

Comment: I tried using inotify on /proc, unfortunately, it does not work :D What a shame.

Comment: Because of the inotify bug, and the lack of any pluggable/hookable stuff for process creation, I accept this solution, as this is what I will do: write a daemon that iterates through processes, and sets their priorities.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it as a kernel module then you could look into making your own binary loader. See the following kernel source files for examples:

```
$KERNEL_SOURCE/fs/binfmt_elf.c
$KERNEL_SOURCE/fs/binfmt_misc.c
$KERNEL_SOURCE/fs/binfmt_script.c
```

They can give you a first idea where to start.

You could just modify the ELF loader to check for an additional section in ELF files and when found use its content for changing scheduling priorities. You then would not even need to manage separate configuration files, but simply add a new section to every ELF executable you want to manage this way and you are done. See objcopy/objdump of the binutils tools for how to add new sections to ELF files.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone of you have any ideas on how to complete this task?

As an *idea*, consider using [apparmor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor) in complain-mode. That would log certain messages to syslog, which you could listen to.

Answer (score 0):

If the processes in question are started by executing an executable file with a known path, you can use the [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) mechanism to watch for events on that file.  Executing it will trigger an `I_OPEN` and an `I_ACCESS` event.

Unfortunately, this won't tell you which process caused the event to trigger, but you can then check which `/proc/*/exe` are a symlink to the executable file in question and `renice` the process id in question.

E.g. here is a crude implementation in Perl using [Linux::Inotify2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Linux%3A%3AInotify2) (which, on Ubuntu, is provided by the `liblinux-inotify2-perl` package):

```
perl -MLinux::Inotify2 -e '
  use warnings;
  use strict;
  my $x = shift(@ARGV);
  my $w = new Linux::Inotify2;
  $w->watch($x, IN_ACCESS, sub
  {
    for (glob("/proc/*/exe"))
    {
      if (-r $_ && readlink($_) eq $x && m#^/proc/(\d+)/#)
      {
        system(@ARGV, $1)
      }
    }
  });
  1 while $w->poll
' /bin/ls renice
```

You can of course save the Perl code to a file, say `onexecuting`, prepend a first line `#!/usr/bin/env perl`,  make the file executable, put it on your `$PATH`, and from then on use `onexecuting /bin/ls renice`.

Then you can use this utility as a basis for implementing various policies for renicing executables. (or doing other things).